# Data model, generic containers, C++

Tags: c++, data-modeling, containers

I am writing a new container as an extension of common STL containers stored in AContainer (an abstract class). For this container I want to add new features depending on stored objects (geometric objects like points, lines, ...)...

But the problem is a little more complicated. For example... There are several types of points (2D, 3D...), most properties are the same ...
Which data model is more appropriate:

1) Universal Container

A derivation of the new class Container from abstract class AContainer common for each type of objects.

```
AContainer -> Container
```

Perform partial specialization for other geomeric objects

```
Container <Point>
Container <Edge>
Container <Polygons>
```

and implement their behavior inside those classes.

But this model brings troubles with the desciption of the same behavior of different types points. I have to specialize Container for Point2D, point3D

```
Container <Point2D>
Container <Point3D>
```

and in both specialization write their behavior, so a lot of code will be duplicated.

In C++ is, in my opinion not possible to do partial specialization for class and all derived classes.

2) Specific container for each type of object

A derivation of new classes for each type of object

```
AContainer ->ContainerPoints
           ->ContsinerEdges
           ->ContainerFaces
```

There are several different containers that could be specialized. The problem with the description of points behavior
will not occur, their common properties will be  defined inside

```
ContainerPoints
```

without need for any specialization...

I'm afraid of too much fragmentation of the code (too much similar classes)... And for example std::vector is universal for each stored type...

Is it better for each geometric type to create a new class or to do a partial specialization?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: It's extremely unlikely you need to write a new type of container.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  template<class T>
  class Container { ... };
  class PointContainer : public Container<Point> { };
```